# Receiving a "doesn't have a comparable type" error when returning a list from an on-chain view

Tags: smartpy, testing, types

When I return a list from an on-chain view am receiving a type error but am unsure where to set the type in order to fix it.

Returning a string or integer from the view works fine. Is there a set limit on the types that can be returned from on-chain views, or is there somewhere I should be explicitly declaring the return types?

I have included a link to a minimal contract on smartpy ide with issue reproduction, and include the code below for reference.

Example Contract:

```
class OnChainViewTestContract(sp.Contract):
    def __init__(self, **kargs):
        self.init(**kargs)

    @sp.onchain_view()
    def run_str_example(self):
        sp.result(self.data.strExample)

    @sp.onchain_view()
    def run_int_example(self):
        sp.result(self.data.intExample)

    @sp.onchain_view()
    def run_list_example(self):
        sp.result(self.data.listExample)
```

The int and str examples work in the tests below, but the list example fails.

```
@sp.add_test(name = "OnChainViewReturnTypes")
def test():
    scenario = sp.test_scenario()
    scenario.h1("On-chain view return types test")
    contract = OnChainViewTestContract(
        strExample = 'some_string',
        intExample = 2,
        listExample = ['a', 'b', 'c']        
    )
    scenario += contract
    
    s = contract.run_str_example()
    i = contract.run_int_example()
    l = contract.run_list_example()

    scenario.verify(s == 'some_string')
    scenario.verify(i == 2)
    scenario.verify(l == ['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

The resulting error:

```
Error: Type error (sp.contract_view(0, "run_list_example", sp.unit).open_some(message = 'View run_list_example is invalid!') : sp.TList(sp.TString)) doesn't have a comparable type
(__main__, line 36)
```

[SmartPy IDE Unit Test Link](https://smartpy.io/ide?code=eJyVkd9LwzAQgN_7Vxx7aTprwFdhIAyfBRm@iISzTbdgmoZcNt1_b5L@WFcUNA@lyX35LnenWts5D9Si8_YMSEA2yyqNRPBktgdU5kXJz50kv@2Md1h5RpaP_8V9BmHVsgEhlFFeCEZSNyWs1x_o9jQAccVzHhk2xrIUewi@zlQxlTiFXKyYnO5oBHkn5Be2Vsuknhstd5KO2qcAr9EjD_hjT_9NrxX5__gjf0kQ5VjXwof@MIOthA2sZn17lv7ozO5sJa2KLOZM5JCDKmnQqS5cCp4YEePR8Mpxyw93LHhvUxkQywCX1OCjO1lX_ZVqGE2Q_jbAS4FTswKdU9fK2G5l9nk5MbOCA_SaY15C_h4_Vf42Qom@fjLcbKa3ZBNDcDnly_H2Ar1ErkZUzFxjc07SqebMgntRRfEjpyO3KKT4BhML868-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot compare lists in Tezos.

However, you can use scenario.verify_equal.

Comment: thank you, is there a list of all incomparable types in tezos somewhere?

Comment: You have a list of characteristics including comparability for each type in this documentation https://tezos.gitlab.io/michelson-reference/.